# i generate random numbers -1 or 1 in 10 cells in the row, in which the sum of the random number in vba is always equal to + values

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

i generate random numbers -1 or 1 in 10 cells in the row, in which the sum of the random number in vba is always equal to + values

Answer (score 1):

use SUMIF():

```
=SUMIF(A1:J1,">0")
```

Comment: Hi, i need all rows add sum don’t leave the -values
I need sum of all row, total must come + values